# In app purchase: sorting array of product identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have the following non-consumable products en RageProducts.swift.

```
public struct RageProducts {

    // MARK: identifiers  product no consumible
    private static let s1 = "comic1" // name in itunnesconnect: Comic Vol 01
    private static let s2 = "comic2" // name in itunnesconnect: Comic Vol 02
    private static let s3 = "comic3" // name in itunnesconnect; Comic Vol 03
    private static let s4 = "comic4"
    private static let s5 = "comic5"
    private static let s6 = "comic6"
    private static let s7 = "comic7"
    private static let s8 = "comic8"
    private static let s9 = "comic9"
    private static let s10 = "comic10" // name in itunnesconnect: Comic Vol 10
    private static let s11 = "comic11"
    private static let s12 = "comic12"
    private static let s13 = "comic13"

    // MARK .-  Set identifiers

    private static let myproductsIdentifier:  Set<ProductIdentifier> = [RageProducts.s1,
                                                                             RageProducts.s2,
                                                                             RageProducts.s3,
                                                                             RageProducts.s4,
                                                                             RageProducts.s5,
                                                                             RageProducts.s6,
                                                                             RageProducts.s7,
                                                                             RageProducts.s8,
                                                                             RageProducts.s9,
                                                                             RageProducts.s10,
                                                                             RageProducts.s11,
                                                                             RageProducts.s12,
                                                                             RageProducts.s13]
//MARK :  Reference to IAPHelper 
    public static let store = IAPHelper(productIdentifiers: RageProducts.myproductosIdentifiers)

}
```

Everything works fine except in the order of when they are displayed in a UITableview, it does not respect the order entered in the array (`Set <ProductIdentifier>`)

**This shows me:**

```
Comic Vol 01
Comic Vol 10
Comic Vol 11
Comic Vol 12
Comic Vol 13
Comic Vol 02
Comic Vol 03
.
.
.
Comic Vol 09
```

**The correct thing should be:**

```
Comic Vol 01
Comic Vol 02
Comic Vol 03
Comic Vol 04
Comic Vol 05
.
.
.
Comic Vol 13
```

**Is there a way to sort them according to the order entered or how could this problem be solved?**

[image: Screenshot of how products are displayed]

Answer (score 2):

Try using an array instead of declaring them one by one

```
public struct RageProducts {

// MARK: identifiers  product no consumible
private static let arrayOfIdentifiers = ["comic1", "comic2", "comic3",
                                         "comic4","comic5", "comic6",
                                        "comic7","comic8","comic9",
                                        "comic10","comic11","comic12","comic13"]

// MARK .-  Set identifiers

private static let myproductsIdentifier:  Set<ProductIdentifier> = [RageProducts.arrayOfIdentifiers]
//MARK :  Reference to IAPHelper
public static let store = IAPHelper(productIdentifiers: RageProducts.myproductosIdentifiers) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but return me: `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Set<ProductIdentifier>' (aka 'Set<String>')`

Comment: Replace `Set<ProductIdentifier>` with `[ProductIdentifier]`

Comment: The type of ProductIdentifier is fixed like this by a tyalias `public typealias ProductIdentifier = String`  so ` private let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>`, so if I change to an array it gives me an error. It seems that storeKit works with Set :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the products: Comic Vol 1, Comic Vol 2, ... Comic Vol 10,...

Comment: The same thing happens :'(